# MATLAB: Are there any problems with many (millions) small files compared to few (thousands) large files?

Tags: matlab, filesystems

I'm working on a real-time test software in MATLAB. On user input I want to extract the value of one (or a few neighbouring) pixels from 50-200 high resolution images (~25 MB).

My problem is that the total image set is to big (~2000 images) to store in RAM, consequently I need to read each of the 50-200 images from disk after each user-input which of course is way to slow!

So I was thinking about splitting the images into sub-images (~100x100 pixels) and saving these separately. This would make the image-read process quick enough.

Are there any problems I should be aware of with this approach? For instance I've read about people having trouble copying many small files, will this affect me to i.e. make the image-read slower?

Comment: Using `'PixelRegion'` option of [imread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) you can read subimages.

Comment: Thanks! That made response time for each input go from a few minutes to a few second, which is good enough for now!

Answer (score 0):

rahnema1 is right - imread(...,'PixelRegion') will fasten read operation. If it is not enough for you, even if your files are not fragmented, may be it is time to think about some database?
Disk operations are always the bottleneck. First we switch to disk caches, then distributed storage, then RAID, and after some more time, we finish with in-memory databases. You should choose which access speed is reasonable.